# MIME pdf for windows 8.1

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-8.1, mime

I'm using MIME to determined the application that's gonna be used to open a file on a Document library for a windows 8.1 application.

```
switch (extension)
        {
            case "DOCX":
                options.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word.document.12";
                break;
            case "EXCEL":
                options.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                break;
            case "PPT":
                options.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation";
                break;
            case "PDF":
                options.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                break;
        }

        await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri, options);
```

Everythings works fine except for pdf file.

Once open, Windows 8 rise an error about file format problem.

Is there anything special to do with windows 8 about pdf file ?

Comment: Can you provide the error log ... ?

Comment: I don't understand why you're changing the content-type for a PDF - it already has the appropriate MIME type.

Comment: @optimus the only message Windows provide me is a Format Error with this file. The error occured when PDF Reader open and it is PDF Reader that raise this error and not my code.

Comment: @MattSmall Cause without this, when I tried to open my file, no program is set to open it...

By the way, I grabing all file from a Sharepoint Document Library. I've noticed that I didn't specify that.

The sharepoint version is 2010.

Comment: Have you tried the following?
1. Examine that the file is downloaded correctly and it is really a PDF file.
2. Try to cache the downloaded file and try to open it manually.
3. Try to open the file manually.
4. PDF Viewer might not support opening files directly from the internet. Try to download the file locally yourself (inside your app) and launch the reader using the local path.

Comment: The purpose of this program is to stream the file from a Sharepoint. I won't download it on the application.

It's a PDF file, I'm the one who upload it on the sharepoint.

The issue is maybe the fourth you ennonced. I'll check this once at work on monday

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the last line

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(fileUrl), options);
```

Comment: If my first parameter is called uri it's for a reason ...

And by the way I've specified that every other file extension works

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdffile);
```

or this one

```
options.ContentType = "application/x-pdf";
```

Comment: LaunchFileAsync required a downloaded file stored in IStorageFile. Here I'm looking for streamed data.

About the "application/x-pdf" it just do nothing. Seems like it's not recognized by the system

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a problem in the Registry, try this :

1) Open Registry Editor **(regedit.exe)** and navigate to the following key: **[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.PDF]**

[image]

2) Double-click the **(default)** value set its data as: **"AcroExch.Document.11"** (without quotes)

[image]

3) Close **Regedit.exe**

4) Restart Windows.

Comment: After launching a research in the registry, this key is unknown.

Comment: Search for ".pdf" and then follow the steps above, change the key for ".pdf" not ".pdfxml"

Comment: Check out the screenshots .